# Python Function of a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a small homework problem, getting my Python function to return the correct values.

Assignment:

> Here is an example dictionary:
>
> ```
> word_freq = {'the': 58, 'people': 6, 'beautiful': 8, 'cats': 13}
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes as parameters: a word frequency dictionary
>   and a threshold number with is an integer. This function should return
>   a result that is a list of all the words whose frequency is greater
>   than the threshold.
>
> For example, suppose that you name your function top_words. If you
>   call the function with the dictionary above and the threshold of 10:
>
> ```
> top_words(word_freq, 10) you should get the result [‘the’, ‘cats’]
> ```

My code:

```
def frequencylist(frequentwords, threshold):
    for keys in frequentwords:
        if key > threshold:
            print(keys)
```

Test run:

```
frequentwords= {'hello':30, 'yellow':4, 'red':10, 'blue':35, 'orange':100}
frequencylist(frequentwords, 10)
```

... and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 3, in frequencylist
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: In the future, take a simple debugging step: print out the offending values just ahead of the error point.  Run again; the last output will likely show your problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys are words; your threshold is an integer.  You can't compare those types with **>**.  I think you mean to compare the value:

```
for key, value in frequentwords.items():
  if value > threshold:
    print(key)
```

This yields the desired output:

```
blue
orange
hello
```

If you also want **red**, you need to change the comparison to **>=**

Comment: Thank you that worked, although i had to change .iteritems to items it said the dict didn't have that attribute

Comment: Whoops!  I program in Python 2.7, and sometimes forget to switch when I'm answering a question.  I'm glad you figured it out.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions is not quite right.  When you iterate (loop) over the dictionary, you are only accessing the key values.  You need to use the built-in `iteritems()` or `items()` functions to get both the key and the value.

```
   def above_thresh(someDict, thresh):
        return [field for field, value in someDict.iteritems() if value > thresh] 

In [6]: above_thresh(frequentwords, 10)
Out[6]: ['blue', 'orange', 'hello']
```

Alternatively, you can fix your approach like this:

```
def frequencylist(frequentwords, threshold):
   toRet = [] 
   for keys in frequentwords: 
        if frequentWords[key] > threshold:
              toRet.append(key)
   return toRet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
print [k for k,v in word_freq.items() if v>=10]
```

It would look like this in a method:

```
def frequencylist(frequentwords, threshold):
    return [k for k,v in word_freq.items() if v>=threshold]
```